# Extracting multiple values from multiple tables from Database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a python list which has multiple lists inside having tables and variables in those tables.
Example:

```
list = [ [ table1, var1 ], [ table2,var2,var3,var4 ], [ table3,var5,var6 ] ] .
```

Can a single `SQL` query be written in `python` to extract the data from all the given tables.

In `SQL` we will write something like this

```
SELECT table1.var1, table2.var2, table2.var3 FROM table1, table2.
```

But in `python` I am facing difficulty as at a time we can have access to only one element, ex: list[0][1],list[1][0] etc.

Comment: Can you show the output you want?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the output? Do you want to create a string containing the SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the list elements dynamically. Assuming your list stores strings and you want to output a string:

```
for tablelist in list:
    for var in tablelist[1:]:
        print(tl[0] + '.' + var)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
[tablelist[0] + '.' + var for tablelist in list for var in tablelist[1:]]
```

To create a string containing the SQL statement from your question:

```
var_accesses = [tablelist[0] + '.' + var for tablelist in list for var in tablelist[1:]]
var_accesses_string = ', '.join(var_accesses)
tables = [tablelist[0] for tablelist in list]
tables_string = ', '.join(tables)
sql_query = 'SELECT {} FROM {}'.format(var_accesses_string, tables_string)
```

Comment: Thanks!! that helped.